# Expressjs - Separation of files and passing arguments

Tags: node.js, express

A simple question really about something I just can't seem to get working...

I am working on a basic rate limiter for my API in a separate file called `limiter.js`. I want every call to run through the limiter so I include it from my `server.js` file.

I am using Redis to store the requests so I need to pass a reference of redis too.

```
//server.js
var limiter = require('./limiter')(app,redisClient);
app.use(limiter.check());
```

How can I make available the `req` and `res` to the file too.

In my `limiter.js` file I have:

```
module.exports = function (app, redisClient) {
  var limiter = {};

  limiter.check = function (req, res) {
    console.log(req) //ERROR: req object does not exist
    var ts = moment().unix();
    var ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
    var key = ip + ":" + ts;
    ...
  };

  return limiter;
};
```

but the `req` object does not exist

Comment: How are you calling `limiter.check`? Sounds like you need to pass `req` in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `app.use` method expects a method, but you're trying to call `limiter.check` and pass the result. Drop the extra parens and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a reference to your method, not call it.

```
app.use(limiter.check);
```

If you want to keep using it how you are now then you need to return a function.

```
limiter.check = function () {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    var ts = moment().unix();
    var ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
    var key = ip + ":" + ts;
    ...
    next();
  }
};
```

PS: Don't forget to call `next()`, otherwise it won't progress through your middleware stack and will hang.